# Change encryption for an existing s3 object

Tags: amazon-web-services, encryption, amazon-s3, amazon-kms

I am looking for a way to change server side encryption of an existing s3 object using AWS SDK.

CopyObject seems to be one of the way to change the encryption type (S3 or AWS KMS) . This does provide way to avoid download of object by having same bucket name as source and destination. However it takes time proportional to size of the file.

Is there an efficient way to change encryption of an existing s3 object?

Comment: Isn't the time for decrypting (and encrypting) a file also proportional to its size?

Comment: thats true... However here is my observation: 
When i change the encryption type for same object from s3 AWS console it takes about 5 seconds. However when i use CopyObject, it took about 25 seconds..

So i am thinking there has to be better way to do this using AWS SDK..?

Comment: The console should be calling the same API as `CopyObject`, and you should be able to confirm this with the bucket logs.  There is no other way to change the encryption -- objects are immutable.

Comment: I second @Michael-sqlbot's comment. To add to that, the console might be calling the API asynchronously, while you're calling it synchronously.

Comment: Thanks Michael and Viccari, will check if bucket logs show API invoked by console. 

Can you please advise how to check bucket logs ? 

This will atleast confirm that API invoked by me and console are same ... if so, asynch operation of API may seem to make it appear faster in console. On second thought, console does show status of operation when i chose to change encryption type of the object. Status does seem to complete very fast as compared to sdk operation...

Comment: @nsv enable logging for your bucket: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ServerLogs.html